# onNotificationPosted not being called after some time

Tags: java, android, notifications, listener

I use [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) to catch notifications and elaborate them in my application. App works great and [onNotificationPosted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#onNotificationPosted(android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification)) is always called, but after a while (Few hours) it stops being called and the app stops working.

**It gets back to work only if I reboot my device or if I revoke and grant again notification access to the application.**

### Important info

- App does have notification access enabled.
- App does have service on AndroidManifest.

  ```
  <service
      android:name=".NotificationService"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService"/>
           </intent-filter>
  </service>
  ```
- App is a release version (Same problem on debug version though).
- It has been tested on Android Lollipop, Marshmallow and Nougat, same result.
- It has been tested in different devices running the same Android version.
- App stops working in both background and activity displayed on screen.
- It works again if I reinstall the application, but this is already included in 'revoke and grant notification access again' previously mentioned.
- **App includes AdMob banner on bottom, is it a possible problem?**

I read Android has a cache problem or something like that. Is this the problem? Is there any permanent solution that I couldn't find anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself here:
https://gist.github.com/xinghui/b2ddd8cffe55c4b62f5d8846d5545bf9

Just create a new class as in the link above, then put in `onCreate`:

```
startService(new Intent(this, NotificationCollectorMonitorService.class));
```

And in AndroidManifest:

```
<service android:name=".NotificationCollectorMonitorService"/>
```

This will restart your NotificationListenerService whenever Android kills it.